# Is there Aforge.NET algorithm for human activity recognition?

Tags: algorithm, aforge, activity-recognition

I was wondering if there is **Aforge.NET algorithm** that is intended for **human activity recognition**?

For example, I would like to recognizing drowning while capturing frames from surveillance camera on the beach.

I saw there are algorithms for motion detection, but what I need is motion detection plus logic to process that motion so that computer can conclude does that motion fit into drowning category or any other category I tell him.

Comments would be appreciated.

Comment: No, I think it's safe to guess that there are no out-of-box algorithms that detect drowning people anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [Accord.NET](http://code.google.com/p/accord/) - it's a library based on AForge.NET that contains many machine learning algorithms. However you must write all the `logic`, as you call it, by yourself.

Another possibility is to use [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which has some motion detection algorithms.

Comment: I have already looked at Accord.NET but if offers even less algorithms in the filed of activity recognition then Aforge.NET. So what should I do? Stick with Aforge or Accord? Thank you for your help

Comment: @AntunTun I've added another possibility, don't know anything else unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will stick with Accord as it has all that Aforge offers plus a new things.

Answer (score 1):

you might need to develop your own algorythms, i do that too with Aforge
Aforge basicly allows me for simple video aquisition, while my math does the interesting stuff.

In your case..
Detect spots with people
Zoom in to them ??
then it becommes tricky how to distinguish someone who dives from someone who sinks ?..
Also there are waves who can get in front of the person your trying to follow..

usually this recognition comes down to simple observations, like someone pulling his hands up is not like a circle of a swimming head..

you got to think how a beach guard can see the difference, what are the main visual clues and how can you convert them to bitmap math.